# LEFT JOIN on a cross tab query

Tags: sql, ms-access

Hoping someone can help me out. I am new to access databases and i am stuck at this part. I have a table with Columns RR,AllOther43. I have done a cross tab with RR as row heading, AllOther43 as column heading and count of AllOther43 as value. The code so far looks like this: [Code picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Tr78.png)

TRANSFORM Count(CompData.AllOtherL43) AS CountOfAllOtherL43
SELECT CompData.Trans_RR
FROM CompData
GROUP BY CompData.Trans_RR
PIVOT CompData.AllOtherL43;

I have another called IRbyRRNEW that also has 2 columns RR and NAME. I want to left join the IRbyRRNEW.NAME with RR from the cross tab query. I have tried a few variations to left join  but i get an error everytime, either with the select statement or FROM statment. Can someone please help me?

Comment: TRANSFORM Count(CompData.AllOtherL43) AS CountOfAllOtherL43
SELECT CompData.Trans_RR, IRRRNEW.Name
FROM CompData Left JOIN IRRRNEW ON CompData.Trans_RR = IRRRNEW.RR
GROUP BY CompData.Trans_RR
PIVOT CompData.AllOtherL43;                                                                   I have this now but i get an error that name is not defined as a aggregate function

Comment: How about if you create a new query, add IRbyRRNEW  and the crosstab as sources and then left join it.